# Creation and execution phase in ECMAScript Specification

Tags: javascript

On many JavaScript related blogs I read about "creation and execution phase" of a script/function but I can't find anything about that in the specification. Is it described somewhere in official spec but called differently or it is just a concept copied from some books and other resources?

example sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

[Are functions set before variables in the javascript 'creation phase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561157/are-functions-set-before-variables-in-the-javascript-creation-phase)

Comment: It'd help a lot if you'd provide context from these sources you've been reading.

Answer (score 2):

There are no "phases" in the spec and they're not called like that, but the concept still exists. You can find this in the [runtime semantics for *EvaluateBody*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluatebody) of a user-defined function:

> 1. Perform ? [*FunctionDeclarationInstantiation*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation)(*functionObject*, *argumentsList*).
> 2. Return the result of evaluating `FunctionStatementList`.

First, all variables are getting declared (the scope and its bindings are created), then the code is executed. Similar wordings can be found whenever a new (block) scope is created anywhere in the spec.